# How to associate the type of a function parameter with a certain enum value?

Tags: typescript, enums, closures

I would like to be able to associate an enumeration and a type when compiling in TypeScript.

The goal to fix the param of a method with an enum. I try to do that with a closure:

```js
enum EnumType {
    TYPE1,
    TYPE2
}

interface Type1 {
    name: string;
}

interface Type2 {
    value: number;
}


function closure(tEnum: EnumType) {
    switch(tEnum){
        case EnumType.TYPE1: 
        return (t: Type1) => { console.log(t); }
        case EnumType.TYPE2: 
        return (t: Type2) => { console.log(t); }
    }
}

const foo1 = closure(EnumType.TYPE1);
foo1({ name: 'test'}); // here no error Type1 (but there is an error)
foo1({ value: 2}); // here error because not Type1
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/wOPXyN)

How do I get this example to work or is there an alternative?

Comment: I don’t see a closure here; since `tEnum` isn’t referenced inside the implementation of the function returned from `closure()`, nothing is obviously “closed over”.  What am I missing?

Comment: [This approach](https://tsplay.dev/wggG0w) is how I'd refactor your code so that it behaves as desired.  Note that I changed your example so that each callback actually cares about the type of `t`; something like a unilateral `t => console.log(t)` doesn't really motivate a switch-case statement.  Let me know if you want to see this written up as an answer or if I'm missing something about your use case.

Answer (score 2):

This is a fairly classic place for using [function overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads):

```typescript
function closure(tEnum: EnumType.TYPE1): (arg: Type1) => void;
function closure(tEnum: EnumType.TYPE2): (arg: Type2) => void;
function closure(tEnum: EnumType) {
    switch(tEnum){
        case EnumType.TYPE1: 
            return (t: Type1) => { console.log(t); }
        case EnumType.TYPE2: 
            return (t: Type2) => { console.log(t); }
        default:
            throw new Error(`Invalid enum value ${tEnum}`);
    }
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

Note that **only** the first two signatures are public; the third is just an implementation signature other code doesn't see.

Comment: Yes, it's works ! Thanks ! 
I had hoped to be able to make a loop to generate all couples with an array {tEnum: EnumType, T}[] but I think it's not possible !

Comment: @bfrances - Ah, yeah, I'm afraid I don't think it is. :-|

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to [function overloads](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71988877/11407695), you can make the association in a utility type and then use [generic type parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#working-with-generic-type-variables) to correlate the type of `tEnum` parameter and the case chosen:

```js
enum EnumType {
    TYPE1,
    TYPE2
}

interface Type1 {
    name: string;
}

interface Type2 {
    value: number;
}

type TypeMap = {
    [EnumType.TYPE1]: Type1;
    [EnumType.TYPE2]: Type2;
};

function closure<T extends EnumType>(tEnum: T): (t:TypeMap[T]) => void {
    switch(tEnum){
        case EnumType.TYPE1: 
        return (t: TypeMap[T]) => { console.log(t); }
        case EnumType.TYPE2: 
        return (t: TypeMap[T]) => { console.log(t); }
    }

    throw new Error(`${tEnum} is not a type`);
}

const foo1 = closure(EnumType.TYPE1);
foo1({ name: 'test'}); // OK
foo1({ value: 2}); // error, OK

const foo2 = closure(EnumType.TYPE2);
foo2({ name: "test" }); // error, OK
foo2({ value: 2 }); // OK
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/wXKg8W)

---

As per [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71988777/how-to-associate-the-type-of-a-function-parameter-with-a-certain-enum-value/71990647#comment127208228_71990647) with [jcalz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2887218/jcalz), it is worth noting that the above example is insufficient if you access properties on `t` inside the `closure` function body as, by virtue of `T` being unresolved yet, `TypeMap[T]` is inferred to be a union `Type1 | Type2`, which means you will not be able to access properties that are not shared by both interfaces there.

An easy solution to this is to drop the `switch` in favour of a plain object matching the `TypeMap` via a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html):

```js
function closure<T extends EnumType>(tEnum: T) {
    const map: { [P in keyof TypeMap]: (t: TypeMap[P]) => void } = {
        [EnumType.TYPE1]: (t) => { console.log(t.name); },
        [EnumType.TYPE2]: (t) => { console.log(t.value); }
    };

    return map[tEnum];
}
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/Nna5qw)

Comment: Your refactoring makes the `switch`/`case` redundant; you can just do [this](https://tsplay.dev/wjZl6w) instead.  That's how I'd approach it unless the example had some runtime motivation for `switch`/`case` (and if it did, I think you'd find your suggestion wouldn't work, [observe](https://tsplay.dev/weXjKW)).

Comment: @jcalz agreed, I just did not go into it since the post was only concerned with how to make the association. Since the `T` is unresolved in the `(t: TypeMap[T}) => ...`, I understand that `t` will be a union `Type1 | Type2` there, hence the inability to access properties unless they are shared by both interfaces.

Comment: To solve the latter, I usually switch (pun intended) from `switch` to something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/Nna5qw). I think it is worth mentioning this in the answer, I'll make an edit.

Comment: Yikes, did not notice you left a comment on the question outlining essentially the same earlier, @jcalz

Comment: ‍♂️ No problem... great minds think alike (and I don't actually want to get in here and add another answer if I don't have to, so )

Comment: Yours is even more concise, @jcalz, haven't thought about simply inlining the association, d'oh 

Comment: @bfrances NP! Btw, you might be interested in [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43873) on the TypeScript source repo about narrowing generic types in `switch` statements (re: my discussion with jcalz) - it is a known limitation and is currently in discussion.